# showing confirmation modal before changing the value of radio button in angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

The radio button inside reactiveform needs to show a confirmation modal in certain situations before changing the value. If the confirm button clicked then change the value. If the cancel button clicked then the radio value remain the same. So inside the click event handler, I'm using the preventDefault to prevent the radio button change immediately.

**app.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="registrationForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <!-- Gender -->
    <div class="group-gap">
      <h5 class="mb-3">Gender</h5>
      <div class="d-block my-3">
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
          <input
            id="male"
            type="radio"
            class="custom-control-input"
            (click)="clickGender($event)"
            value="male"
            name="gender"
            formControlName="gender"
          />
          <label class="custom-control-label">Male</label>
        </div>

        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
          <input
            id="female"
            type="radio"
            class="custom-control-input"
            (click)="clickGender($event)"
            value="female"
            name="gender"
            formControlName="gender"
          />
          <label class="custom-control-label">Female</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Submit Button -->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block">
      Submit
    </button>
  </form>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
async clickGender(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const value = e.target.value;
  const otherFieldTrue = this.registrationForm.get('otherField').value;
  if (otherFieldTrue && value !== 'male') {
    let confirm = await this.showConfirm();
    if (!confirm) {
      return;
    }
  }
  this.registrationForm.get('gender').setValue(value);
}
```

The problem is after changing the value by clicking the confirm button the value of the radio can't be switched back. Also, when there is no need to show the modal, the radio can't be changed.

Here is the stackblitz example:
[enter link description here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-confirm-dialog-using-matdialog-d3wmuw?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you are always `e.preventDefault()` which disables native browser control value switch. Moving it inside `if` statement fixes the issue

```
  async clickGender(e) {
    const value = e.target.value;
    const otherFieldTrue = this.registrationForm.get('otherField').value;
    if (otherFieldTrue && value !== 'male') {
      e.preventDefault(); //Prevent radio switch only here
      let confirm = await this.showConfirm();
      if (!confirm) {
        return;
      }
    }
    this.registrationForm.get('gender').setValue(value);
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-confirm-dialog-using-matdialog-lfqfne?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thanks. This fixed my problem. I thought the setValue would work since after clicking confirm button on modal, the radio did switch.

Comment: It did switch but not because you have clicked it but rather becuase you set the value of control via this.registrationForm.get('gender').setValue(value);